# Unable to click on Manage option of "Microsoft App ID" in Azure Bot channel registration

Tags: botframework

I have created a Azure Bot threw bot channel registration but when i click on Setting -> (Microsoft App ID) Manage link, it always show "Not Found" page. 
can any one help to resolved this issue.

Comment: Do you have multiple accounts that you can use to sign in to apps.dev.microsoft.com?

Comment: No, i have only one account which is main admin.

Comment: Can you see your bot's app registration from the list of your app registrations in Azure? https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationsListBlade

Comment: Yes, i can see my boat's app registration from above url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug that prevents MSA accounts from navigating to their App Registration from the bot settings blade if they didn't make their own app registration when creating the bot. I am working on a fix right now, but in the mean time you can go to `https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps/ApplicationMenuBlade/Overview/appId/{insert app id here}/isMSAApp/true` or `https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/application/{insert app id here}` to manage your app registration.

July 29th edit: A fix for this has been rolled out and it should be fixed for MSA accounts.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will use this way.

Comment: This is still happening in 2022 btw, the URL workaround still worked though